# Virus in Rails Gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I just started seeing this in my app when I'm either uploading to heroku or just running the app in my local environment. Anyone seen this before?

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       <html>
       <head>
       <title>ttack.tk</title>
       <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; URL=http://domain.dot.tk/p/?d=TTACK&i=107.21.141.33&c=1&ro=0&ref=unknown&_=1368664428485"/>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       <!--
       function redir(){ var $fwd = 'http://domain.dot.tk/p/?d=TTACK&i=107.21.141.33&c=1&ro=0&ref=unknown&_=1368664428485'; if(window.parent){ window.parent.location=$fwd; }else{ window.location=$fwd; }}
       //-->
       </script>
       </head>
       <body onload="redir()">
       <script language="text/javascript">
       <!--
       window.setTimeout('redir();', 500 * 1);
       //-->
       </script>
       </body>
       </html>
       Compiled jquery_ujs.js  (0ms)  (pid 1028)
       Compiled bootstrap-transition.js  (0ms)  (pid 1028)
```

Comment: Good find. I would call this malware rather than a virus, though. Maybe just me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the domain the gemattack gem is on was compromised.   Check your Gemfile.lock to see what depends on gemattack and update/remove that.  See

https://github.com/mauriciozaffari/gemattack/issues/1

It's probably mongoid_search, so I recommend updating that gem.

Comment: Thanks! Shawn. Saved.

Comment: Doesn't work with me, i updated everything. And i can't find gemattach. Any other ideas?

Comment: @SeifSallam Try bundle update mongoid_search

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci Thanks. It, worked but i don't understand why. I ran gem update and it updated everything. Why did it work with bundle update ?

Comment: @SeifSallam Bundler determines what gems you use even if you have later versions installed.  You were still using the earlier version (in Gemfile.lock) until you did the bundle update.